# How can I specify the number of “grades” in an array of integers by user input?

Tags: c

I’ve used the method below to achieve my goal, but to no avail.

• I want the user to specify the number of grades.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 

{
  int user;
  int grades[user], i;

  for(i=0; i<grades[user]; i++) {
    printf("Please enter a value: ");
    scanf("%d", &grades[i]);
  }

  //Printing out the array

  for(i=0; i<grades[user]; i++) {
    printf("\nIndex Number: %d Value: %d\n", i, grades[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &user)`? Do that before using `user` anywhere.

Comment: because `int grades[user]` uses the value of `user` *at that time*, which is indeterminate.

Comment: and you probably need `for(i=0; i<grades[user]; i++)` to be `for(i=0; i<user; i++)` Even if that was right, it is illegal to index an array by its length. You can only index `grades[]` from `0` to `user-1`.

Comment: If you have an outside maximum number of users (say 256), then `#define nusers 256` and declare `int grades[nusers] = {0};` to a normal array instead of a VLA (*Variable Length Array*). If you have no idea, you can simply allocate with `malloc()` and `realloc()` (or just use `realloc()` for all.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int main(void) 
> {
>  int user;
>  int grades[user], i;
> ```

At this point the value of `user` is uninitialized, so using it as the size of a variable length array is undefined behavior.

Rather, use `scanf` to read in the value of `user` *before* you use `user`.

```
scanf("%d", &user);
```

Remember to check the return value of `scanf` to ensure you actually read in an integer.